# Why do I get NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop?

Tags: java, swing, exception, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to open an `URI` with Swing that I get above error.

What is the reason and how can I fix it?

When I do it in console everything is OK but when I do in GUI I get this error.
I should say that I use Weblogic as server.

**Code**

```
private static void open(URI uri) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) { /* TODO: error handling */ }
    } else { /* TODO: error handling */ }
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.BcfiDownloadPanel.open(BcfiDownloadPanel.java:230)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.BcfiDownloadPanel.access$000(BcfiDownloadPanel.java:37)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.BcfiDownloadPanel$7.actionPerformed(BcfiDownloadPanel.java:147)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
```

Comment: What is the [java.version](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.version) of the JRE that is running this code?  [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) is a 1.6+ class.

Comment: As an aside, this has the Swing tag yet you mention the WebLogic server (servers might be 'headless' - no GUI allowed).  This confuses me.  Is this code running on the server or on a remote client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc on [NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

You do have some incorrect classloading happening. Mostly due to wrong class loader chaining.

Comment: @itro My answer was not a complete one, it was only a hint. Glad it helped. What was the 'real fix'?

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` can only be caused by a **classpath** problem.

Because `Desktop` is part of **jre**, make sure that your **classpath** contains a reference to the **jre** library.

In **Eclipse**, you can go to **run configurations** --> **Classpath** and check there

**UPDATE:**

As Andrew suggested, you can also check you have at least java 1.6

Comment: If the JRE was not in the classpath, `URI` would not be found.

Comment: Are you sure? I think the JRE library only needed to be in the CLASSPATH for the very first versions of Java.

Comment: @AndrewThompson maybe his classpath is disordered and one of the jars in it contain an incomplete jre and this is from where the URI is being found

Comment: @AndrewThompson Also, how are you sure that URI comes from jre and not from a class he created or in another jar?

Comment: *"how are you sure that URI comes from jre"*  The OP mentioned URL when the method actually specified an URI.  I doubt someone at that level will be using a custom version of the URI class.  I'll even offer you 100:1 odds. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Desktop` has been introduced [in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html). Chances are high you're running your code on different JRE versions.