# How to launch browsers from swing in java?

Tags: java, swing, exception, browser, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984256/why-do-i-get-noclassdeffounderror-java-awt-desktop)

**I want to launch browsers that i get following error:**

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop`

**What is the cause and how to fix it?**

```
private static void open(URI uri) {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
             //TODO: error handling
        }
    } else { 
        //TODO: error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984256/why-do-i-get-noclassdeffounderror-java-awt-desktop) may help.

Comment: @c24w That's link to same author's duplicate question :D

Comment: As someone already answered the first time you asked this question, you should check your JRE version

Comment: @itro : it's working like a charm, better if  you post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in a good way. As told by Adel Boutros(in previous thread), the problem lies with your Java classpath. Installing it anew, might solve your case, get a new copy of Java seems like yours is broken somewhere.   Regards :-)